# What cloud VPSes do you run your tezos nodes on and is alphanet taking forever to sync for you also?

Tags: alphanet

I'm trying to compare best performance for the tezos-node on AWS, DigitalOcean, Linode, etc.  On which provider and instance type do the blocks sync the fastest and which provider and instance type is the most reliable to use for this purpose?

Comment: that was previously discussed https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/704/extremely-slow-node-sync-on-alphanet/

Comment: We use [DigitalOcean - referral](https://m.do.co/c/16894ea0bca1) 2CPU/2GB ($15/month) droplets. They are perfect for Tezos since baking 1 roll vs 100 rolls requires the same amount of minor CPU (never above 10% CPU). Using the IronTez branch, disk usage is under 20GB as well.